# if function "derivative" is infinite somewhere, is it necessarily continuous around that point?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

if $ \lim_{x \to a^{+}} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = +\infty $
, is the function f continuous on  $ (a, a+\epsilon) $  for some small $\epsilon>0 $ ?
if that's the case, can someone please provide with a proof relying on $\epsilon \delta$ definition of limits and continuity and really basic knowledge of real analysis (i just started real analysis on my own, not a math major so i don't know many theorems), Thank you in advance

Comment: What If $a=0$, $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=1/x$ if $x> 0$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ If $x<0$ where $g$ is discontinuous?

Comment: Did you really mean to look at the limit on $x>a$ but continuity on $x<a$?

Comment: sry i meant in the interval $(a, a+\epsilon)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a=0$. Take any function $h\geq 0$ such that $h(0)=0$. Then $f(x)=h(x)+ \sqrt{x}$ will satisfy the hypothesis
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x}\geq\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {\sqrt x}{x} =+\infty. $$
If in addition $h$ is not continuous on any interval $(0,\epsilon)$, then $f$ isn't as well. So the question becomes: can you think of a function $h\geq 0$ that is not continuous on any interval $(0,\epsilon)$, $\epsilon>0$? It should be easier for you to find one. Tell me if you need a hint on that.

---

**Edit**. The above limit is infinite because, since $f(x)\geq\sqrt x$, you have
$$ \liminf_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}\geq\liminf_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt x}{x}=\liminf_{x\to 0^+}x^{-1/2}=+\infty. $$
Since the limsup is always greater than the liminf, the limsup is $+\infty$ as well, so that
$$ \liminf_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\limsup_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}=+\infty, $$
so the limit exists and is $+\infty$.

---

**Comment**. Morally, prescribing the derivative at some point $a$ tells you nothing on the continuity of the function around $a$.

A related example is the following. Choose any function $0\leq f(x)\leq x^2$ on the interval $(-1,1)$. Then, you can check that
$$ 0=\liminf 0\leq\liminf_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\leq\limsup_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\leq\limsup_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}x=0, $$
so that all the above quantities are zero, and $f'(0)=0$. So $f$ is differentiable (hence continuous) at $x=0$, but it is surely possible that such an $f$ is discontinuous at any other point. For instance, take $h$ to be the function equal to $0$ over the rationals and $1$ over the irrationals, and set $f(x)=x^2\cdot h(x)$. Then $h(x)=f(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous for any $x\neq 0$, so $f$ must be discontinuous at any given point $x\neq 0$ (otherwise $h$ would be continuous as a product of continuous functions).

Comment: h(x)=0 if x in Q and f(x)=1 if x in R\Q

Comment: however i dont understand why limx→0+(f(x)−f(0))/x=+∞. exists when h is not continuous

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: Yup, that function $h$ works. This means that $f(x)=h(x)+\sqrt x$ is a counterexample to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f$ on ${\Bbb R}^+$ as follows,
$$f(x)=\cases{\frac1x&if $\frac1x$ is not an integer\cr
              \frac1x+1&if $\frac1x$ is an integer,\cr}$$
together with $f(0)=0$.  Then for every positive integer $n$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to1/n}f(x)=n\ ,\quad f\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)=n+1\ ,$$
so $f$ is discontinuous at $x=\frac1n$.  But for the difference quotient at $0$ we have
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}\ge\frac1{x^2}\to\infty\quad\hbox{as}\quad x\to0^+\ .$$

Comment: nice function, thank you.